# Is Laravel right choice for my project or some other is better

Tags: php, entity-framework, cron, laravel-4

We are planing to make a new system to replace our 10 year old system, in doing so we are considering to make the new system in Laravel. Now I have concerns I will have to hack the whole thing and make it a mess to make it work as we wish. So I am asking if someone knows a better solution for it, or can tell that it is already made in it.

we need:

- ftp, sftp, which are cron triggered.
- mail daemon which is cron triggered.
- easy way to implement multiple factories and easily to encapsulate them (i am thinking to use the model part for it)
- easy possibility to switch the global database connection
- inter server connectivity
- caching functionality like memcache built into the database layer and object layer
- possibility to tell the framework which pulls get stored in cache
- an easy Templating system, ye i know i can make one easy, but some which is already done in Laravel would help :)
- we have our own servers so module installations are not a problem.
- Unit test implementations on factory based systems.

All suggestions are welcome, if i am by any chance in the wrong stack overflow part please just say in which section i should move it. Thank you in advance for all feedback :)

UPDATE->

The requierements above are minimum requirements for us/me to consider the framework good enough. If somone is able to point to tutorials how to do the stuff with laravel. Please provide links. In special Unit testing Laravel controllers, cron setup from Laravel... and so on..

Answer (score 2):

This is truly a question only to be answered by you and your team (in terms of effectiveness, language understanding and framework pattern knowledge).
Laravel can surely withstand such projects and migrations but most of the frameworks out there can do, personally I've been using Laravel and Cakephp in terms of PHP frameworks and find both of them quick, efficient and easy to use (with Laravel code a bit more easily to read through large projects).

On the other hand there are frameworks out there which efficiently do what you need quicker and easier than most php frameworks, django (python) is one example, stable, lightning fast development (if you are already familiar with python concepts) and proven (instagram, disqus etc).

Nearly all frameworks have known RDBMS support, but are a bit back in terms of NoSQL support (yet you can find plenty of projects that provide support for NoSQL), Laravel can easily switch DB's but compared to the "DB router" feature of Django I believe it feels a bit behind on how much detail has been put to it.

Comment: Frameworks are supposed to make us work faster, be more productive. So, once of the "tests" I use when selecting between new frameworks is the "hello world" test. How long does it take to get to hello world? I then rank based on that, and use it as part of the decision making process. Good answer!

Comment: Well my question is something like that. But my Hello world is at minimum what i wrote down. Without that, it is not usable.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is a beautiful framework, but this isn't a stackoverflow type question.  None of us will be able to really give good advice, other than say Laravel is good.

Answer (score 0):

Let me refine the question. I am not asking for opinion if i am using the right framework, i need some hard data.
I already know Zend 2 (working with it 1.5 years) and it is to bulky and to developer footprint heavy for our project(our logic would have to be developed into the damn thing... just not practical).
I already work with Cake, and it is to simple for us, 
Symphony i know to, but it has BIG problems with our structures.
Code igniter is.... to simple... and so on and on...

I am currently reading trough Code Bright Book for introduction of the possibility's from Laravel. And i am half trough. But i have not found anything that tells me it can help my project with the points which are pointed out.

So i am asking again, i need examples of the points implementations in its simplest way for comparison. except in Zend, Code Igniter and Symphony.